# How can I combine multiple setup files into one big setup file?

Tags: windows-7, combine

I am looking for a **free** program that combines multiple install files to one setup file. I want to be able to run one file to install many programs, one by one, and I want it to be able to run unattended.

Right now, whenever the OS is reinstalled, I have to install programs one by one and I have to sit there until all are finished being installed.

There are some online programs which I do not want.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: What are those online programs you don't want? You could also build an MSI package that can do what you want. But it will take some time and skill.

Comment: Why not just create a System Image Backup after installing all your required files?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could give [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) a try.

Comment: thanxs, but this app will first download & then install all programs..  i have all the set up files, so i do not want to download ..I've restricted internet bandwidth  //

Answer (score 0):

You could write a batch file to install all of the files, but the problem lies in the installer for each of the programs.  If even one of the programs doesn't have an option to allow for unattended installation, you're still going to need to sit and click through dialogs until the install finishes.

Comment: thanxs buddy,,, i got the point

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested answer, but...

In theory, if you know a bit of programming (namely VB Scripting), you could try **AutoIT v3** (basically a macro tool that sends keystrokes & mouse-input and supports window management).

You would essentially be coding the steps to reproduce the manual installations of each software dialogs / wizards into a series of ENTER key-presses, TAB, entering field information, check/uncheck boxes, etc. A few window-title checks might be required to wait until it's done before you carry on to the next step or installer.

Albeit sounds like a lot of work - depending on your total of computers (and how often) this needs to be done on, it could save you a LOT of time and even return some back for a coffee break! :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: Once your script is tested and "done", you can create an *.exe of it so you won't have to install AutoIT v3 on every computers. Heck, could even place everything on a disk with an autorun.ini file (if those are even still used anymore)